# Button onclick in function

Tags: javascript, function, button

I'm trying to solve this problem. First step is create a table after clicking on first button. Later the table is creating and one row has another button which should starting another function play() with arguments. For this example I just want to display ready in console but this is undefined. When I call this function by simply console.log outside the function then is working correctly. What is wrong with calling function play by button?

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
            <th>Team A</th>
            <th>Team B</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
</table>
  <button onclick="create()">Create next Match</button>

const table = document.querySelector('.table');

const teams=[{
  name: 'Real',
  point: 10
},
            {
  name: 'Barca',
  point: 20
}]

function create(){
  table.innerHTML += `
<tr id="r1m1">
            <td id="host">${teams[0].name}</td>
            <td id="guest">${teams[1].name}</td>
            <td id="host_score"></td>
            <td id="guest_score"></td>
            <td><button onclick="play(${teams[0]},${teams[1]})">Play</button></td> 
        </tr>`
}

function play(a,b){
  console.log("ready");
}

console.log(play(teams[0],teams[1]))
```

Comment: When you substitute an object into a template literal, you get `[Object object]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use template substitution, just refer to the variables in directly in the `onclick`, just like when you call `play()` in the top-level code.

```
function create(){
  table.innerHTML += `
<tr id="r1m1">
    <td id="host">${teams[0].name}</td>
    <td id="guest">${teams[1].name}</td>
    <td id="host_score"></td>
    <td id="guest_score"></td>
    <td><button onclick="play(teams[0],teams[1])">Play</button></td> 
</tr>`
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mashing strings together, so `teams[0]` gets converted to `[object Object]` which not only doesn't contain the data you want, but also isn't syntactically valid JavaScript.

You might be able to manage with `onclick="play(teams[0],teams[1])"` but scope might trip you up (as `teams` and `play` **must** be globals, which are best avoided in general).

In general, your should use DOM methods like `createElement`, `addEventListener` and `appendChild` instead.